# Home router - VPN - TOR setup. Is it possible?

Tags: configuration, raspberry-pi

What I have on mind is this:

home router --> Raspberry Pi 01 VPN --> Raspberry Pi 02 TOR --> internet

Raspberry Pi 01 would connect to router via wifi and the two Raspberry Pis would be connected via ethernet, and finally Raspberry Pi 02 would be set up to AP.

Point of this setup: hide TOR usage and broadcast a tor wifi network.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to route traffic between a few computers? Of course. But if you're looking to hide Tor usage, you're betting off using a pluggable transport. As for broadcasting a "Tor wifi network", that's quite a bad idea, since many programs on connected computers may deanonymize the user to the Tor exit node.

Comment: on the mac that is connected to the TOR WiFi, I use another VPN for that purpose. Many sites block tor nodes so that is a must.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking at OnionPI, that is a way to set up such a access point.

https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview

Also, you do have routers with built in tor capabilities for wifi.
I have one of these, and that's the 'Netgear WNR3500L v2' which I flashed with Tomato USB - http://tomatousb.org/

That let's me set up a wifi which is automatically routed through tor.

Comment: actually I am already using an Onion Pi, I set it up following the tutorial that you linked. It works fine, but I want to get another Pi with a VPN to chain them so that I will not connect TOR directly therefore hiding the tor usage.